# Can't seem to sendkeys to debugview

Tags: windows, sendkeys

On windows 7:

Trying to send "<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> -- ipadress - <kbd>RETURN</kbd>" to connect to a remote debugview.

Even if SetForeground window passes nothing happens from any of the keys. Even alt-f4 does nothing.

I know the syntax/external conditions should be correct because if I switch to a different window keys are sent if I <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> to debugview it still doesn't seem to pick up an keys.

UAC is set to lowest level.

Comment: could you check the formatting changes I have made?

Comment: does debugview run elevated (run as administrator) whereas the process you send from does not? even if UAC is set to low, i believe this will still not be allowed

Comment: ben yes it does appear to be because its sending them to an elevated process. Sending from an elevated process works. If you submit this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does debugview run elevated (run as administrator) whereas the process you send from does not?

Even if UAC is set to low, I believe this will still not be allowed. 
A solution would be be to either run the target process un-elevated or to elevate the process that triggers the sendkeys.